How can I determine an error on total noise?
I am analyzing the data for an experiment, where we measured the total noise in a system. The total noise is defined as the variance of the signal (and is equal tot the integral over the noise spectral density). How can I find an error on this? I have the error on the value of each data point in time. Could I take the standard deviation on the variance?

As a suggestion, you may want to consider also posting on https://math.stackexchange.com/ , https://dsp.stackexchange.com/, or https://stats.stackexchange.com/ as the reviewers there may have also some perspectives of interest.  Depending on the underlying noise process, I can imagine there being a variety of answers.

If you measured the noise multiple times, you could calculate the standard deviation of the noise.

A good resource to consider is:    Bendat and Piersol "Measurement and analysis of random data" https://archive.org/details/measurementanaly00bend/page/13/mode/1up

OMG, this is what I get paid to do. But, yes, the standard error on the variance is fine.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156518/what-is-the-standard-error-of-the-sample-standard-deviation say it's:
$$ SE(\sigma^2) = \sqrt{\frac 1 n (\mu_4-\frac{n-3}{n-1})}$$
One thing I do is, just generate a gazillion distributions and measure the variance of the statistic off concern.
Wolfram used to have a break down up to kurtosis, but I can't find it anymore.
but I am not sure.

I recommend that you use [bootstrapping][1]: Bootstrapping assumes that your dataset represents the population, and that the data points are independent. If we accept these assumptions, we can resampled (with replacement) from the dataset and generate several "bootstrap samples". For each "bootstrap sample" we calculate the statistic of interest $T$ -- in your case the variance $T=Var[X]$. Thus, we obtain a distribution of the statistic of interest, which allows us to estimate the uncertainty of the statistic of interest, $Sd[T]$.
Bootstrapping is a great tool, if the statistic of interest is dominated by the "body" of the distribution. Instead, if the statistic of interest is dominated by rare event, lying in the "tails" of the distribution, bootstrapping is probably useless.
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#:~:text=Bootstrapping%20is%20any%20test%20or,etc.)%20to%20sample%20estimates.
